# How to open a door with no(or half?) a doorknob

Tags: doors, lock, doorknob

I was studying in my living room when a gust of wind from the open window closed my bedroom door. I didn’t mind because, even though my doorknob is always falling off, I usually keep it close to me in case something like this happens.
It never did, and the only time it closed completely, I forgot it in my room
I saw another question here with a similar situation but here’s where I’m screwed: the other guy doorknob fell off completely, in my case, the piece of iron that connects both side is still attached, and I cant move or insert anything
I got no idea what to do

Sorry if anything sounds weird, english is not my first language

Here’s a photo of how it looks like[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have two(break a longer piece) flat(rulers) pieces of stiff material, tie them together at one end and squeeze the other end with the square piece between them.

It should be enough to turn the square piece to open the door.

Comment: Or just use a wrench or pliers to turn it....

Comment: if you have those tools use them  if not the pull tab from a drink can has a square hole, If you are trapped call a neighbour, or the fire department....

Comment: A set of vise grips would make short work of that problem.

Comment: I am going on the assumption that the OP might not have tools handy and has not had the pleasure of watching MacGyver.

Comment: I disagree with tool, but the concept is correct: The knob operates by turning the squared shaft. If you turn that, with whatever tools you have or can make it can borrow, you should be able to retract the spring latch. Of course you also have to retract the deadbolt, using the thumb-turn below, if that hasn't already been done.